# How to detect continually key event?

Tags: c++, mfc

Now I know MFC has a function:PreTranslateMessage to detect key event
But if I want it detects continually key event?
Such as "0 0 enter"
When the program detects it, the program will do some operation

Can anyone help me?

Comment: So you want to detect a key chord? Or what?

Comment: Rather badly worded and unclear about the intent. That's why I voted to close as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: sorry, my mother language is not English. It is sorry that my question cannot be expressed clearly

Answer (score 0):

Simple one word answer: States.

Longer explanation: When you detect the <kbd>0</kbd> key you set a state flag to inform you that one zero has been pressed. When you receive the next key-press you check this state variable to know what to do: If it tells you that you have received one zero, and the current key is also <kbd>0</kbd> then you alter the state to reflect that you have received two zeroes. If the key is *not*  then you reset the state. This way it's easy to know if you have no, one or two zeros entered, so that when you get <kbd>Enter</kbd> then you know what to do.